# How share fb app's canvas page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I have made a fb app that change it's output everytime when user refresh the canvas page. I want to share the canvas page . Here's my code
function share() {

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: '<?= $appname;?>',
     link: '<?= $canvasURL;?>',
     picture: '<?php echo $callBackURL.$appimagename;?>',
     caption: '<?=$wallpub;?>',
     description: '<?= json_encode(strip_tags($line, ''));?>',
     actions: [{ name: '<?= $walllink;?>',text: '<?= $walllink;?>',link: '<?= $canvasURL;?>', href: '<?= $canvasURL;?>'}],
     message: ''
   },
function(response) {
     if (response && response.
     _id) {
       //alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       //alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
}
```

Made a button to make it work

```
<FORM><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" OnClick="share();" VALUE="Share with friends" class="submitButton"></form>
```

Looks everything ok. But not working properly. See demo in this [app](https://apps.facebook.com/futurewife_palash)

Any help would be very helpful

Comment: Can you explain what is "not working properly"? What is happening and what do you expect instead to happen?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Please see the demo , I want to share the current canvas page to the user's wall. it's noted that canvas page differs to users @Flaxfield